# Kohana 3.1 routes with default subdirectories

Tags: php, kohana

I have an application that is essentially working until I tried to implement an Auth module for logins and registrations.

My application directory structure is basically:

```
application
-- classes
  -- controller
     -- admin
        (admin area)
     -- block
        (blocks to display within pages)
     -- page
        (default pages)
```

By default I want to have URL's such as http://www.testsite.com/test which would access the Controller_Page_Test class. Or to explicitly call admin or block pages http://www.testsite.com/admin/test which would access the Controller_Admin_Test class. To further complicate matters it also needs to handle optional actions and id's.

I said at the top that this is basically working correctly - until I've tried to add in the Auth module. The Auth module calls http://www.testsite.com/user/login but instead of accessing the module's path via the default, it looks in the page directory.

To overcome this I placed a higher level route but now this has become my default page handler. Explicit calls still get through.

My routes currently look like this:

```
Route::set('user', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))', array('controller' => 'user|admin_user'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action'     => 'index',
        'id'         => NULL,
    ));

Route::set('with_dir', '<directory>/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))', array('directory' => 'block|admin'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'page',
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

Route::set('just_id', '<controller>(/<id>)', array('id' => '\d+'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'page',
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

Route::set('auto_dir', '<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))', array('id' => '\d+'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'page',
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));


Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'prototype',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Can this be cleaned up any better? And how do I get this module to only kick in when I need it to?

Comment: All your routes look too much alike, so eventually some of your uri's get weird results due to the wrong route being chosen. Also, take a look at lambda routes, maybe they solve some of your problems: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing#lambdacallback-route-logic

Comment: Thanks Luwe. I struggle really 'getting' how routes work and it is a lot of trial and error for me. I'll have a read through the link. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be cleaned better. Kohana developers encourage people using this framework to **add as much routes as needed**. You can even specify them for each action which will enable you to change URLs in the future (eg. instead of `/user/login` you may wish to have `/signin`), if you use proper methods to generate links etc. (eg. `Route::url()` helper).

Now, saying that, here is the other way to specify the `user` route:

```
Route::set('user', '<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))', array('controller' => '(user|admin_user)'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Which will match only the requests, where the first part of the URI is given and is equal either to `user` or `admin_user`. Previously the controller part was optional, thus was also matching calls to `/` URI.